# C# RegEx - get only first match in string

Tags: c#, regex

I've got an input string that looks like this:

`level=<device[195].level>&name=<device[195].name>`

I want to create a RegEx that will parse out each of the `<device>` tags, for example, I'd expect two items to be matched from my input string: `<device[195].level>` and `<device[195].name>`.

So far I've had some luck with this pattern and code, but it always finds both of the device tags as a single match:

```
var pattern = "<device\\[[0-9]*\\]\\.\\S*>";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = rgx.Matches(httpData);
```

The result is that `matches` will contain a single result with the value `<device[195].level>&name=<device[195].name>`

I'm guessing there must be a way to 'terminate' the pattern, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: No time for a full answer but the key is non-greedy matching. Put a `?` after the * to make it match the minimum possible (nongreedy) as opposed to the most possible (greedy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [non-greedy quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers):

```
<device\[\d+\]\.\S+?>
```

Also, use verbatim strings for escaping regexes, it makes them much more readable:

```
var pattern = @"<device\[\d+\]\.\S+?>";
```

As a side note, I guess in your case using `\w` instead of `\S` would be more in line with what you intended, but I left the `\S` because I can't know that.

Comment: Now I'd like the person who downvoted to prove me wrong... http://regex101.com/r/kX3hK2/1

Comment: @Lucas `?` after `\d*` is not required, cause `\d*` will never match the `]`. Also your regex will match on `<device[].>` - which is way to common.

Comment: @dognose You're right about the `?`, I guess I got too used to using non-greedy by default. The end result is exactly the same though. I left the `*` because that's what was in the OP and I don't know the asker's use case. Still, does that make it a bad answer?

Comment: @dognose: do you have inside knowledge of the users input strings? saying `<device[].>` is way to common seems rather bizarre to me since its not a string I see often and its certainly not a string that OP says he has...

Answer (score 3):

I want to create a RegEx that will parse out each of the `<device>` tags

```
I'd expect two items to be matched from my input string: 
   1. <device[195].level>
   2. <device[195].name>
```

This should work. Get the matched group from index 1

```
(<device[^>]*>)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/kI0gJ6/1)

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"(<device[^>]*>)"
```

Comment: leave a comment please.

Comment: @dognose I didn't got it. Have a look at demo

Comment: @dognose don't make any such inputs that is not supposed by OP.

Comment: Also your "perfect match, dude" example is ridiculous since it isn't anything like the string that the OP says he has.

Comment: It that is case then there are thousands of ways where I can invalidate it.

Comment: As per input it should be only `[195]` isn't it?

Comment: So, matching "barely everything" as long as ops example is covered is a good regex? Then the overall regex answer would be `^.*$` ...

Comment: @Braj Common, there is a clear statement, that there should be numbers enclosed in `[]` - your regex does NOT contain anything about that. So, wheres your point?

Comment: @dognose read first line *I want to create a RegEx that will parse out each of the `<device>` tags* and there is nothing written as it should contains number inside `[]`

Comment: @Braj well, he didn't literaly say it - but from his regex attempt and the provided example, one can derive that requirement. Anyway - it's "your" answer, not mine :)

Answer (score 3):

depends how much of the structure of the angle blocks you need to match, but you can do

```
"\\<device.+?\\>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your repetition operator and use `\w` instead of `\S`

```
var pattern = @"<device\[[0-9]+\]\.\w+>";
```

---

```
String s = @"level=<device[195].level>&name=<device[195].name>";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"<device\[[0-9]+\]\.\w+>"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Output

```
<device[195].level>
<device[195].name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use named match groups and create a linq entity projection. There will be two matches, thus separating the individual items:

```
string data = "level=<device[195].level>&name=<device[195].name>";

string pattern = @"
(?<variable>[^=]+)     # get the variable name
(?:=<device\[)         # static '=<device'
(?<index>[^\]]+)       # device number index
(?:]\.)                # static ].
(?<sub>[^>]+)          # Get the sub command
(?:>&?)                # Match but don't capture the > and possible &  
";

 // Ignore pattern whitespace is to document the pattern, does not affect processing.
var items = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select (mt => new
                  {
                     Variable = mt.Groups["variable"].Value,
                     Index    = mt.Groups["index"].Value,
                     Sub      = mt.Groups["sub"].Value
                  })
                 .ToList();

items.ForEach(itm => Console.WriteLine ("{0}:{1}:{2}", itm.Variable, itm.Index, itm.Sub));

/* Output
level:195:level
name:195:name
*/
```